# SQL Query takes too long - temporay tables

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with an sql query on MySQL which is running way to long. Would appreciate your help on how to optimize it.

The query in question runs on a table with around 8000 rows that looks like this:

```
price_id int(5) Primary Key with auto increment
product_id int(5) 
price_amount float
price_date date
```

Basically, it holds historic prices of several products, so that you can generate an invoice relevant to any historic date.

The problematic query in question has to give me the most updated price of a list of products relevant to a certain date. For example, to get the relevant price of product_id 1, 2 and 4 as to September 1st, it would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM prices
WHERE price_id IN (
     SELECT max(prices.price_id) 
     FROM prices
     WHERE product_id in (1,2,4) AND price_date <= '2016-09-01' 
     GROUP BY product_id
)
```

Now, this query runs for aaaaaages. It varies, but right now for example, for 3 product_ids it took about 58 seconds to run. Usually the invoices have around ~120 products in them (takes a few minutes to return results) so you can imagine the trouble..

I profiled the query in phpmyadmin, and basically it looks like this:

```
Status                        Time 
Sorting result                0.000050 
Sending data                  0.000025 
executing                     0.000009 
Copying to tmp table          0.008586 
Sorting result                0.000052 
Sending data                  0.000026 
executing                     0.000006 
Copying to tmp table          0.008118 
Sorting result                0.000057 
Sending data                  0.000029 
executing                     0.000011 
Copying to tmp table          0.007498 
Sorting result                0.000047 
Sending data                  0.000021 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.008479 
Sorting result                0.000056 
Sending data                  0.000031 
executing                     0.000011 
Copying to tmp table          0.007371 
Sorting result                0.000059 
Sending data                  0.000031 
executing                     0.000011 
Copying to tmp table          0.006702 
Sorting result                0.000045 
Sending data                  0.000019 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005319 
Sorting result                0.000034 
Sending data                  0.000015 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005302 
Sorting result                0.000035 
Sending data                  0.000016 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005207 
Sorting result                0.000031 
Sending data                  0.000014 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005243 
Sorting result                0.000034 
Sending data                  0.000016 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005236 
Sorting result                0.000035 
Sending data                  0.000016 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005185 
Sorting result                0.000035 
Sending data                  0.000015 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005256 
Sorting result                0.000033 
Sending data                  0.000017 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005160 
Sorting result                0.000025 
Sending data                  0.000014 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005149 
Sorting result                0.000024 
Sending data                  0.000013 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005356 
Sorting result                0.000038 
Sending data                  0.000016 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005221 
Sorting result                0.000034 
Sending data                  0.000016 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005189 
Sorting result                0.000033 
Sending data                  0.000015 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005370 
Sorting result                0.000038 
Sending data                  0.000017 
executing                     0.000005 
Copying to tmp table          0.005208 
Sorting result                0.000035 
Sending data                  0.000017 
executing                     0.000006 
Copying to tmp table          0.005209 
Sorting result                0.000036 
Sending data                  0.000054 
end                           0.000019 
removing tmp table            0.000021 
end                           0.000008 
query end                     0.000006 
closing tables                0.000020 
freeing items                 0.000052 
Waiting for query cache lock  0.000006 
freeing items                 0.000852 
Waiting for query cache lock  0.000012 
freeing items                 0.000004 
storing result in query cache 0.000019 
logging slow query            0.000005 
logging slow query            0.000010 
cleaning up                   0.000009 

Showing rows 0 - 2 ( 3 total, Query took 58.6074 sec)
```

So I would guess by the numbers, most of the time is spent creating temporary tables. (max heap and temp table size parameters are at their 16M defaults).

Does anyone have any idea how I can speed this query or design a new query that does the same but much more efficiently?

Comment: Query Optimization and Relational Algebra!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dinamic from  (   )  and inner join  on the resulting table

```
  select * from prices as a 
  inner join (      
       SELECT max(prices.price_id )  as max_price_id
       FROM prices
       WHERE product_id in (1,2,4) AND price_date <= '2016-09-01' 
       GROUP BY product_id ) t on t.max_price_id = a.price_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated query,sometimes mysql has a problem with IN subqueries

```
SELECT prices.* 
FROM prices 
WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT max(p.price_id) 
     FROM prices p
     WHERE p.product_id in (1,2,4) AND p.price_date <= '2016-09-01' 
     AND prices.price_id = p.price_id
     GROUP BY p.product_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are free to add indexes, index the table by (1) product_id, (2) price_date (descending) and you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM prices
WHERE product_id in (1,2,4) AND price_date <= '2016-09-01' 
ORDER BY price_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: wouldn't that return just a single product ? we need the prices for all three products